# JavaFX scaling does not resize the component in parent container

Tags: java, javafx

I have a container that needs to display two custom components scaled down by 25% aligning them vertically.
I'm using a VBox loaded from this FXML:

```
<fx:root type="VBox" fx:id="leaderDisplay" xmlns="https://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"  fx:controller="MyController"
        prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="200.0" alignment="CENTER">
</fx:root>
```

And the component is loaded from this FXML:

```
<fx:root stylesheets="@css/style.css" type="StackPane"
         maxHeight="294.0" maxWidth="195.0"
         fx:controller="MyOtherController"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <AnchorPane fx:id="cardPane" styleClass="leader-card" prefHeight="294.0" prefWidth="195.0">
      <FlowPane fx:id="lcRequirements" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="10.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lcVictoryPoints" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="162.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="20.0" text="0" />
   </AnchorPane>
   <Pane fx:id="cardBack" styleClass="leader-card-back" maxHeight="294.0" maxWidth="195.0" visible="false" />
</fx:root>
```

I add the needed components programmatically with this method in the VBox controller:

```
private void addLeader(LeaderCard newLeader) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");

        LeaderCardWidget newWidget = new LeaderCardWidget(newLeader);

        System.out.println("Height before: " + newWidget.getMaxHeight());
        newWidget.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 3");

        newWidget.setScaleX(0.75);
        newWidget.setScaleY(0.75);

        System.out.println("Height after: " + newWidget.getMaxHeight());
        leaderDisplay.getChildren().add(newWidget);
        leadersAndWidgets.put(newLeader, newWidget);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the components are being scaled down, but the vbox does not display them properly, leaving huge spacing around them (to the right is the same screenshot without scaling for reference):

[image: With scaling]
[image: Without scaling]

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Wrap the components each in a `Group`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "Visual Bounds versus Layout Bounds" section of the [layout documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html):

> `Node` provides the layoutBounds property to define the 'logical'
> bounds of the node for layout and boundsInParent to define the visual
> bounds once all effects, clipping, and transforms have been applied.
> ...  if a `ScaleTransition` is used to pulse the size of a button,
> that pulse animation will not disturb layout around that button. If an
> application wishes to have the effect, clip, or transform factored
> into the layout of a node, it should wrap that node in a `Group`.

In short, transforms, such as scaling, are not factored into the layout calculations of the parent. You can make that happen by wrapping your components in a group. I think you can achieve this in your code with

```
// leaderDisplay.getChildren().add(newWidget);
leaderDisplay.getChildren().add(new Group(newWidget));
```

Comment: This is the exact thing that I needed, thanks!